# SFSL error while encrypting password in snowflake

Tags: database, encryption, insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, password-encryption

I am trying to insert the password in a table using `encrypt()` function provided by a snowflake.

The below statement is working fine

```
 select  encrypt('Patient tested positive for COVID-19',  $passphrase);
```

but when I am trying to use the variable instead of direct string password inside `encrypt()` I am getting an error(below query is giving an error)

```
set acc_name = 'acc1';
set username = 'username1';
set password = 'passtemp';
set passphare = 'random_string';

insert into db.public.detailstable values ($acc_name,$username,encrypt($password, $passphare));
```

**Error:**

```
SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [ENCRYPT(:SFSL_A2_0, :SFSL_A2_1)] in VALUES clause
```

**Create table statement:**

```
create or replace TABLE detailstable (
accountName VARCHAR(16777216),
username VARCHAR(16777216),
password BINARY(8388608)
);
```

Comment: Possibly not the answer to your particular problem but you should always explicitly list the columns you are inserting into rather than assume that Snowflake (or any DBMS) is going to use the columns you expect in the order you expect

Comment: Also, please update your question with the CREATE statement for your target table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VALUES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#required-parameters) clause in an INSERT requires a literal, expression, default value, or NULL. The result of the *encrypt* function call does not satisfy that requirement. The following statement will work.

```
insert into db.public.detailstable
select $acc_name, $username, encrypt($password, $passphare);
```

Comment: I deleted my answer that we submitted at about the same time. The edit to add the list of what's supported in the VALUES clause is the key here. +1 for referencing the list.